# Android build configurations for multiple customers

Tags: android, maven, build, build-process, maven-3

I have Android application that needs to be delivered to multiple customers.
For every customer I have different graphics and configuration XML files which specify features and URLs.

At build time we should be able to specify the customer for which the application should be built. Then resources (like images and run-time configuration) appropriate for the specified client should be built into the app.

The project is build with Maven.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ended up using maven profiles and 'renameManifestPackage' and 'resourceOverlayDirectory' properties of the android maven plugin.

The default res/ dir is overriden by 'resourceOverlayDirectory' specific for every customer.

It worked out great.

```
<!-- profile for zurich -->
<profile>
  <id>zurich</id>
  <properties>
    <customer>zurich</customer>
    <customerPackage>zurich.com</customerPackage>
    <customerResources>customers/${customer}/res</customerResources>
    <customerApkName>${customer}-${project.artifactId}</customerApkName>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

and in the build I have:

```
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

  <!-- the name of the generated apk and jar -->
  <finalName>${customerApkName}-${project.version}</finalName>

  <pluginManagement>

    <plugins>

  <!-- customer specific manifest and package -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <renameManifestPackage>${customerPackage}</renameManifestPackage>
      <resourceOverlayDirectory>${customerResources}</resourceOverlayDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </pluginManagement>
```

Comment: does this copies over the actual `res` folder, or they are all copied in the `target` folder?

Comment: Great. Do you have problems when trying to install two applications on the same device?

Comment: @EugenMartynov no, the package names are different.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know how well this is supported for Android projects, but the usual way is to define a profile for each customer. In each profile you should override the relevant resource directories with the ones for the specified customer.

Comment: Yes, that is the usual way, but because android resources are statically linked it can not be done that easy.

Comment: Then you override the whole 'linking' step. In the end it just calls aapt on a bunch of files, so it should be possible. If not, there's always library projects for Eclipse or Ant. Check how they do it in Ant, should give you some ideas.