# Use different resources (graphics and strings) for different application flavors using gradle

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

There are already several questions on this ([different icons which didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460095/how-to-provide-different-launcher-icon-per-product-flavour) and [different names which did work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607020/how-to-change-android-app-name-in-the-build-gradle-file)), but the answers to those aren't yet quite enough to get my app working the way I need. I'm brand-new to Gradle, just started converting to it yesterday, and there are just a couple things I haven't been able to figure out.

I have 3+ apps working off the same codebase, each using different app launcher icons and names, URLs, but right now I can't get the different icons and app names to work for each app. Before I added the sourceSets, my appName and other custom strings worked, but the icon didn't, and now nothing works.

Inside my src directory, I have 4 directories: `flav1`, `flav2`, `flav3`, and `main` (contains all my core code and default resources). Android Studio has tacked `.res` onto each the end of each `flav` Each directory has a drawable and values directory with the custom strings.xml and icon.png, respectively, inside. I don't if drawable is supposed to have a specific name: drawable, drawable-mdpi, etc. If it's just whatever I decide, I want drawable.

I'm not getting any errors, just the default strings defined in `main` and the default icon Android Studio, except my default AndroidManifest.xml inside `main` won't recognize my icon and them anymore.

Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 19
   buildToolsVersion '19.0.2'

   defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion 8
      targetSdkVersion 19
   }

   buildTypes {
      release {
         runProguard false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
      }
   }

   productFlavors {
      flav1 {
         packageName "com.example.flav1"
         versionCode 32
         versionName "1.0.5"
      }

      flav2 {
         packageName "com.example.flav2"
         versionCode 33
         versionName "1.0.6"
      }

      flav3 {
         packageName "com.example.flav3"
         versionCode 27
         versionName "1.0.0"
      }
   }

   sourceSets {
      main {
          // I don't understand how these are supposed to work
          java.srcDirs = ['java']
          resources.srcDirs = ['src']
          aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
          renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
          // res.srcDirs = ['res']
          assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
      }

      flav1 {
          // I can't figure out the path to these
          res.srcDirs = ['res', '/flav1']
      }

      flav2 {
          res.srcDirs = ['res', '/flav2']
      }

      flav3 { 
          res.srcDirs = ['res', '/flav3']
      }
   }

   // I read that these are necessary, but I don't know how to use them
   sourceSets.flav1 {
      res {
          srcDir 'flav1'
      }
      resources {
          srcDir 'flav1'
      }
   }
   sourceSets.flav2 {
      res {
          srcDir 'flav2'
      }
      resources {
          srcDir 'flav2'
      }
   }
   sourceSets.flav3 {
      res {
          srcDir 'flav3'
      }
      resources {
          srcDir 'flav3'
      }
   }
}

dependencies {
   // code
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can rearrange your files, that's the simplest way to fix this.

You want to put them like this:

```
yourApp/
  src/
    main/
      java/
      res/
    flav1/
      java/
      res/
    flav2/
      java/
      res/
    flav3/
      java/
      res/
```

Then in build.gradle, you can get rid of sourceSets entirely. Keep productFlavors.

As far as the overriding of resources, it should be automatic: "The build system merges all the resources from the all the source directories. If different folders contain resources with the same name for a build variant, the priority order is the following: build type resources override those from the product flavor, which override the resources in the main source directory."

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Through your answer, and other help, I was actually able to realize that just having the `drawable` in each flavor wasn't enough to overwrite it. So I added the other folders within res with the icon within them: `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-ldpi`, etc. I don't actually know which one overwrote the default, but that gave me success. 

Am I right in assuming that the `java` directory would hold any custom code for a specific class or something for that particular flavor?

Comment: One more question: what is meant by the `build type resources`?

Comment: I am just full of questions today: Is there an easy way to extend this solution to include `debug` and `release` versions for each of the above flavors so I can specify different URLs for each?

Comment: build type is something like release or debug. You already have a buildTypes for release in your example. Yes, you can define different properties for a build type. To do that, in addition to main and flav1 etc, you can have a directory debug/ and release/, each with their own res and java subdirs.

Comment: Yes, java would hold custom code. This is unusual, but not unknown.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! However, I'm a bit confused on how to create a debug and release version for each flavor. All I really need is a different url for each. I don't know how to use the release section of the BuildType to specify different urls for debug and release versions of each flavor, and the website isn't helpful there. Wouldn't a directory debug/ and release/ just create two new flavors, rather than two types for each already-existing flavor? Minus the java directories, what you show above is what i have. Do I make a debug and release directory for each flavor? Thanks again!

Comment: You are talking about build variants: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-system-concepts. In your environment they'd be named flav1Debug, flav1Release, etc. Also see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Type-Product-Flavor-Build-Variant