# unable to load the strings from es-rCO

Tags: android, localization

I have created 2 localisation folders in src like tr and es-rCO. when I run tr debug build app name pick the value from tr folder values.
But its not working for es-rCO.

please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you renamed the folder values-es-rCO or values-es

Comment: No unable to load strings from specific country localisation folder like some values folders are contains "-r" from those

Comment: followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226722/use-different-resources-graphics-and-strings-for-different-application-flavors . Created flavours under src

Comment: Have you checked your device support Colombian locale?

Comment: am doing force localisation using "select build variant Type" . so it does not depends on device language.

Comment: below one is the solution for this above: created a folder in src with the flavour name and added drawables.