# Android App Environments

Tags: android, continuous-integration

Is there a way in android to have environment specific resources? I mean without having to "program it in" whereever i need them. I would like to be able to set an environment during build (with hudson) and everything is referenced based on the environment.

The most obvious two scenarios would be debug / release build.

I would like to be able to have environment specific resources like strings, arrays, colors, drawables, etc:

- test backend / production backend
- test data for dev/test environment
- environment specific tokens/keys for webservices
- etc

I worked with apache common configuration before on other projects. How to achieve similar configurability with an android project?

Cheers
-d

Comment: The functionality seems to be there already: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources using qualifiers for resources. If i only could introduce my own qualifiers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to achieve this. You can read the debuagable parameter from android manifest and read resources based on this.

```
boolean isDebuggable = (packageInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0;
```

But this is no good.

If you use Maven you can try the profiles and 'resourceOverlayDirectory' approach described here https://stackoverflow.com/q/7568065/590531

Comment: That's my current approach, but i don't like the fact that i could eventually compile resources into my app which don't belong there. I comment them out for release or comment them in for debugging which is error prone.