# Android Development Stages/Targets (Development/Testing/Release)

Tags: android

There is any way to setup the application to have multiple targets, for example i want to build for development, testing and release.  Is this possible?

It's possible to install the same app twice on the phone,  if i want to have installed development version and release version. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know of is to use maven and use the `renameManifestPackage` option. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552033/android-build-configurations-for-multiple-customers).

Comment: Thanks! I've never use maven. I'll try it :)