# create a generic application and build automation

Tags: android, maven, generics, ant, build-automation

I have a generic newspaper application that has been customized to 6 different applications.

The only changes are

1. Package name
2. Some constants (in class file and resources)
3. images and Icons

The problem is when there is a change its difficult and time consuming to apply these changes to all apps.
Is there a way to automate this process , I think there has to be ,guess maven and ants are supposed to do this.

Can someone help me with some tutorial or any other option for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Maven**

You can definitely do that, here couple useful links (if you are already familiar with Maven itself):

[Android build configurations for multiple customers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552033/android-build-configurations-for-multiple-customers)

http://tech.ebuddy.com/2013/04/08/branded-android-builds-using-maven/

**Gradle**

The new Android build system, based on Gradle, also support multiple product "flavor", but is still under development:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system